# options.inInputShareable used when downloading an image from internet

Tags: android

I have the following code in my project:

```
        public void downloadFromUrl(URL url) {
            try {
                /* download the image */
                URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
                cn.connect();
                InputStream is = cn.getInputStream();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                options.inInputShareable = true;
                mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
                is.close();

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

My question is, since inInputShareable is set to true, the bitmap will share a reference to the input data (inputstream). Does it mean the bitmap will always hold a reference to the InputStream? Should I call is.close() in my code? I am afraid if is.close() is called, the data in the InputStream will be lost. Thanks.